# SteamVR performance test says my GeForce GTX 980 Ti is not ready for VR

Tags: gpu, virtual-reality

I am thinking about getting a Vive and I wanted to check if my PC can handle it. My motherboard and processor are pretty old (Asus M4A79XTD EVO ATX AM3 and AMD Phenom II X4 965 3.4GHz respectively) but I recently upgraded to a GeForce GTX 980 Ti graphics card.

When I ran the Steam VR test program, I was expecting it to say that my graphics card was OK but that my CPU was a bit too slow. Actually, it's the other way round. [Screenshot of steamVR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQTGu.png).

> Your system isn't capable of rendering low quality VR and it appears to be >mostly bound by its GPU.
>
> We recommend upgrading your Graphics Card

I've made sure I have updated my NVidia drivers.

When I look in GeForce Experience, I get the picture I was expecting to see:
[GeForce Experience screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6QEA.png). It thinks my graphics card is OK but my processor doesn't meet the minimum spec.

But, since the Steam VR test is actually rendering stuff, whereas the GeForce experience is just going by the hardware I've got, it makes we think that my GPU should be capable but something about my setup is throttling it.

I'd love to know what the problem might be. Perhaps because I'm using an NVidia card in an AMD chipset MB?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I never found out exactly what the cause was but the problem is now resolved. I bought a new Motherboard, processor and RAM but kept the graphics card. After getting everything booted up, the system is reporting "high-quality VR" for both CPU and graphics card.

So, for whatever reason, it does seem like the MB/processor was throttling the graphics card in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Steam VR only tests if your rig is able to keep steady frames over 75fps. I can run VR on my laptop and it's only got a GTX 960m. My CPU is a little more up to date. I7 6700k 16gb of ddr4. I also have a buddy able to run VR on a 780ti.